# Что за галочки и замки в Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

Что за галочки и замки в Visual Studio напротив классов и не только?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Это значки от подключенной в Visual Studio системы контроля версий -- скорее всего TFS или git. Они отображают текущее незафиксированное (т.е. не попавшее в репозиторий) состояние файла:

- Замок означает, что файл не был изменен.
- Галочка означает, что файл был изменен.
- Плюсик (на скриншоте его нет, но такая иконка тоже существует)
  означает, что это новый файл.